# Convergence or divergence of the integral $\int\limits_{10}^\infty \frac{e^x}{x^{1 + \frac{1}{x}} (e^x -1)} \,dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

I want to calculate $  \displaystyle \int_{10}^\infty  \cfrac{e^x}{x^{1 + \frac{1}{x}} (e^x -1)}dx = \lim_{R \to \infty}\int_{10}^R  \cfrac{e^x}{x^{1 + \frac{1}{x}} (e^x -1)} \, dx $. I think that it will diverge by bounding it below with $\frac{1}{x}$. So how do we calculate this integral?

Answer (score 3):

Note that

$$\cfrac{e^x}{x^{1 + \frac{1}{x}} (e^x -1)}\sim\frac 1x$$

then the integral diverges by limit comparison test with $\int \frac1x dx$.

Comment: Can you please explain how do we get this result?

Comment: @Ninja The asympthotic estimation is trivial then it suffices to refer to limit comparison test and show that $$\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{\cfrac{e^x}{x^{1 + \frac{1}{x}} (e^x -1)}}{\frac1x}=1$$ to conclude.

Comment: I really cannot see the trivial relation unfortunately.

Comment: @gimusi  Your comment makes no sense really. And the word "trivial" is inappropriate here.

Comment: @Ninja What I mean with trivial is that we don't need detailed derivation for the estimation, indeed since $1/x\to 0$ and $e^x>>-1$ we can make the given estimation (it is a brutal force step). We make all rigorous by limit comparison test and in this step we need to calculate the limit in a rigorous way.

Comment: @zhw. See my comment. What I mean with trivial is that we don't need detailed derivation for the estimation but we need of course to proof the limit rigoursly.

Comment: After dividing the integrand by $1/x$ we get $\cfrac{e^x}{e^x -1}\cfrac{x^{-1/x}}{1}$. then what do we do?

Comment: recall that $x^\frac1x\to 1$

Comment: So we get the limit as $1$ but how do we conclude that the left handside is greater than $1$?

Comment: Refer to https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1906781/505767

Comment: Limit comparison test is very useful because we can avoid direct comparison by inequalities which are not always simple to find and prove.

Comment: @Ninja Refer also to https://math.berkeley.edu/~ehallman/math1B/compTest-proof.pdf

Comment: @Ninja By that test if $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\to L<\infty$ then $\int f(x)$ and $\int g(x)$ have the same behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

Since $x^{-1/x}$ decreases for $x>e$ and $\frac{e^x}{e^x-1}$ decreases for $x>0$, then we have for $x>10$

$$\frac{e^x}{x^{1+1/x}(e^x-1)}> \left(\frac{e^{10}}{10^{1/10}(e^{10}-1)}\right)\,\frac1x$$

By comparison, the integral diverges.

Comment: Why $\cfrac{e^x}{e^x -1}  $ decreases for $x>0$=

Comment: But it does decrease for $x>0$.  Note that $$\frac{e^x}{e^x-1}=\frac{1}{1-e^{-x}}$$which has a derivative that is less than $0$ for $x>0$.