# Is $ \int_{-2}^{2}\frac{e^{-x}}{\sqrt{x+2}}\text dx $ convergent?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

> **Is  $ \int_{-2}^{2}\frac{e^{-x}}{\sqrt{x+2}}\,\text dx $ convergent?**

$$\int_{-2}^{2}\frac{e^{-x}}{\sqrt{x+2}}\,\text dx=\int_{-2}^{0}\frac{e^{-x}}{\sqrt{x+2}}\,\text dx+\int_{0}^{2}\frac{e^{-x}}{\sqrt{x+2}}\,\text dx$$

So the convergence depends of $\int_{-2}^{0}\frac{e^{-x}}{\sqrt{x+2}}\,\text dx$ :

$$\int_{-2}^{0}\frac{e^{-x}}{\sqrt{x+2}}\,\text dx=\lim_{a\to -2}\, \int_{a}^{0}\frac{e^{-x}}{\sqrt{x+2}}\,\text dx$$

Wolfram says the integral converges, so I triend to find  $f(x)\geq\frac{e^{-x}}{\sqrt{x+2}}$ and  easy to integrate.

My first idea was $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2+x}}$ but this function in $[-2,0]$ is not greater than $\frac{e^{-x}}{\sqrt{x+2}}$.

I'm stuck in this point, so can you help me or give me some hint? Thanks.

Comment: You can use limit comparison test to avoid directy comparison by inequalities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have that

$$\int_{-2}^{2}\frac{e^{-x}}{\sqrt{x+2}}\text dx=\int_{0}^{4}\frac{e^{-{(y-2)}}}{\sqrt{y}}\text dy$$

and for $y\to 0^+$

$$\frac{e^{-{(y-2)}}}{\sqrt{y}}\sim \frac{e^{2}}{\sqrt{y}}$$

thus the given integral converges by limit comparison test with

$$\int_{0}^{4}\frac{1}{\sqrt{y}}\text dy$$

Comment: Thank you so much! and  how can I prove it using the limit comparison test that you said before?

Comment: @B.David Refer to https://math.berkeley.edu/~ehallman/math1B/compTest-proof.pdf and to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1906781/limit-comparison-test-for-improper-integrals

Answer (score 2):

Your integral is $e^{-2}\int_0^4 x^{-1/2}e^{-x} \text dx\le e^{-2}\int_0^4 x^{-1/2}\text dx=2e^{-2}[\sqrt{x}]^4_0=4e^{-2}$, so is finite.