# What $\alpha$ makes $\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \big{(}\frac{1}{\sin(x)}\big{)}^{\alpha}$ converge

Tags: calculus, analysis

So the question is for what $\alpha$ our integrand is integrable. I started with the fact that $$\sin(x)\leq x$$ in this interval $$\therefore  \ \frac{1}{\sin(x)}\geq \frac{1}{x}$$ So the function diverges for all ${\alpha\geq 1}$ I suspect that it might be convergent for $\alpha \in (0,1)$ but I cannot bound it from above with a function for which it is true.

Comment: Why don't you bound it with $\frac{2x}{\pi}$ in the other direction?

Comment: @Diger Will do my friend. thanks

Comment: @Kacper Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have that for $x\to 0^+$

$$\frac{1}{\sin x}\sim \frac{1}{x}$$

therefore by [**limit comparison test**](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1906781/limit-comparison-test-for-improper-integrals) with $\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \big{(}\frac{1}{x}\big{)}^{\alpha}dx$ the given integral diverges for $\alpha\ge1$ and converges for $\alpha<1$ .

Comment: yeah that was my motivation, but I cannot that "the function behaves like [...]" I need rigorous proof.

Comment: @Kacper The rigorous proof can be done by the limit comparison test, it is a theorem which allow us to conclude the behaviour of the given integral by the behaviour of the other.

Comment: @Kacper It is a powerful and useful criteria which avoid the direct comparison test based on inequalities which can be more difficult to be applied in general.

Comment: Refer also to http://www.math.toronto.edu/mat137/files/137_LCT2.pdf

Comment: Yeaj sorry I did not get what you wanted to do, I understood it even before I read your comments. I take bak what I said ;)

Comment: but wait if in the notation from the link I want limit to be finite then my $g(x)=1/sinx $and my $f(x)=1/x$ and $f(x)/g(x)\to 0$ as $x\to \infty$ and from the theorem convergence of $\int g(x)$ $\Rightarrow$ convergence of $\int f(x)$

Comment: The point of interest can be any $x\to a$, refer also to https://services.math.duke.edu/~cbray/Stanford/2003-2004/Math%2042/limitcomp.pdf

Comment: all right, sorry for being tedious...

Comment: @Kacper You are right, it is not simply find some good reference on that on the web. Refer to some good calculus book on the topic.

Answer (score 0):

$g(x)=\frac{x}{\sin x}$ is increasing and bounded between two positive constants for $x\in(0,\pi/2)$. It follows that
$$ K^{\alpha}_1\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{dx}{x^\alpha}\leq\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sin(x)^{-\alpha}\,dx \leq K^{\alpha}_2\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{dx}{x^\alpha}$$
and the middle integral is convergent iff $\alpha<1$ as expected. You may compute it its closed form in terms of the $\Gamma$ function through Euler's Beta function, leading to
$$ \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sin(x)^{-\alpha}\,dx = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\cdot\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\alpha}{2}\right)}{\Gamma\left(1-\frac{\alpha}{2}\right)}\qquad \text{for Re}(\alpha)<1.$$
If you are just interested in discussing real values of $\alpha$, you may exploit the fact that due to the non-negativity and continuity of the sine function over $(0,\pi/2)$, $M(\alpha)=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sin(x)^{-\alpha}\,dx = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{dz}{z^\alpha \sqrt{1-z^2}}$ is non-negative and log-convex where it is defined, as a consequence of the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality and the fact that $\text{continuous}+\text{midpoint-convex}$ implies $\text{convex}$. $\lim_{\alpha\to 1^-}M(\alpha)=+\infty$ is fairly straightforward, hence the domain of $M$ cannot extend beyond $1$.