# Show if the integral converge or diverge

Tags: calculus, integration, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

For this integral $$ \int_0^{\infty} x^3 e^{-x} dx$$

I need to show if it converges or not!

I calculated it by integration by parts and I found that it converges (this is the only way I know to prove the convergence) but it is needed to prove it  <strike>using the convergence tests</strike>  without calculating it and I don't know how to apply them here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have that the function is continuous and

- $x\to 0\implies x^3 e^{-x}\to 0$

then we have

$$\int_0^{\infty} x^3 e^{-x} dx=\int_0^{1} x^3 e^{-x} dx+\int_1^{\infty} x^3 e^{-x} dx$$

and the first one is a proper integral while the second one converges by limit comparison test with $\int_1^\infty \frac1{x^2}$, indeed

$$\frac{x^3 e^{-x}}{\frac1{x^2}}=\frac{x^5}{e^x}\to 0$$

Refer also to the related

- **[Limit comparison test for Improper Integrals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1906781/limit-comparison-test-for-improper-integrals)**

Comment: @user008 Without direct calculation, we can use LCT with $\int \frac1{x^2}$ as $x \to \infty$.

Comment: @user008 've added some more step to be more precise with the derivation.

Comment: @user008 We need to be sure that as $x\to 0$ the integrand to not diverge. Therefore we can split the integral in two parts. The first one is a proper integral which then converges. For the second part we use the LCT with a convergent integral and since the limit is $0$ the convergence is assured.

Comment: `For the second part we use the LCT with a convergent integral` so we can divide by \frac{1}{x^5} instead of \frac{1}{x^2}?

Comment: @user008 We can use any $\frac1{x^a}$ with $a>1$.

Comment: If it is possible for a last question: you also divided the integral into: the first proper between ($0$ and $1$) and the second improper! Can I do the same but to set the bounds for the proper as $ \int_0^{2}$ or generally $\int_0^{c}$

Comment: @user008 Yes of course. In this case any $c>0$ works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative approach: since $g(x)=x^3 e^{-x/2}$ is non-negative and bounded by $6^3 e^{-3}$ on $\mathbb{R}^+$ (since $g'(x)$ only vanishes at $x=0$ and $x=6$) we have $\int_{0}^{+\infty}x^3 e^{-x}\,dx = \int_{0}^{+\infty} g(x) e^{-x/2}\,dx \leq 2\cdot 6^3 e^{-3}$.

We may also interpolate this inequality: for any $a\in(0,1)$ we have
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}x^3 e^{-x}\,dx \leq \frac{27 e^{-3n/a}}{a^3(1-a)} $$
and by picking the optimal $a=\frac{3}{4}$ we get $\int_{0}^{+\infty}x^3 e^{-x}\,dx\leq\frac{256}{e^3}.$

A further generalization leads to
$$ n! \leq (n+1)^{n+1}e^{-n}. $$

Answer (score 1):

Recall:

$e^n =1+n+n^2/2!+...n^5/5!..> n^5/5!$

1) $0 < a_n:=n^3e^{-n} < 5!n^{-2}:=b_n;$

$s_n:=\sum_{k=1}^{n} a_k$ converges

since $r_n:=\sum_{k=1}^{n}b_k$ converges (comparison test).

2) Integral comparison test for series ;

Let $f: [1,\infty] \rightarrow \mathbb{R^+}$ a monotonically decreasing  function then

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f(n)$ converges $\iff $

$\int_{1}^{\infty}f(x)dx$ converges,

$f(x):=x^3e^{-x}$;

$f(n)=a_n$ in 1) and we are done.