# How to show $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x}{\sqrt{\sin x}}dx<\infty$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I was thinking of upper bounding it by $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{\sin x}}dx$ but that is an elliptic integral and does not have a closed form solution. Any suggestions?

Comment: Note that $\frac{x}{\sqrt{\sin x}}<\pi/2$ on $(0,1)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $\sin x\geq x-\dfrac{x^{3}}{3!}$, $0\leq x\leq 1$ and $\displaystyle\int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{\sin x}}dx\leq\int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x-x^{3}/6}}=\int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^{2}/6}}dx\leq\int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1-1/6}}dx<\infty$.

\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{x}{\sqrt{\sin x}}dx\leq\int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{\sin x}}dx.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

We have that

$$\frac{\frac{x}{\sqrt{\sin x}}}{\frac1{\sqrt x}}=x\cdot \frac{\sqrt x}{\sqrt{\sin x}}\to 0$$

therefore the given interal converges by [limit comparison test](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1906781/limit-comparison-test-for-improper-integrals) with $\int_{0}^{1}\frac1{\sqrt x}dx$.

As an alternative note that as $x\to 0$

$$\frac{x}{\sqrt{\sin x}}=\sqrt x\cdot \frac{\sqrt x}{\sqrt{\sin x}}\to 0$$

therefore the integral converges.

Answer (score 1):

Since
$$\lim_{x \to 0+0} \frac{x}{\sqrt{\sin(x)}}=0$$
We can extend the domain of $x \mapsto \frac{x}{\sqrt{\sin(x)}}$ to $[0, 1]$ with value $0$ at $0$. The new function is continuous on $[0,1]$, so it will be Riemann integrable there.

Answer (score 0):

We can bound this integral like this $\displaystyle\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x}{sin 
 {x}^{1/2}}dx\leq\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{sin {1}}dx$ and this obviously converges.