# For what values of $a$ does $\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} (\cos{x})^a \ dx$ converge?

Tags: definite-integrals, improper-integrals

> For what values of $a$  does $\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} (\cos{x})^a \ dx$ converge?
> $a\in \mathbb{R}$

How to approach this problem?

EDIT:
For $a\ge 0$ the $\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} (\cos{x})^a \ dx$ converges. The only problem is for $a<0$. My guess for $-1<a<0$ the $\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} (\cos{x})^a \ dx$ converges and for $a\le-1$ it doesn't. I'm not sure how to approach this formally.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Can such an integral diverges? $\cos x$ is a nice function and the interval is compact nothing could go wrong

Comment: @IrbidMath Well, *something* can go wrong where $\cos x=0$.

Comment: For $a\geq0$ you have a continuous function on all of $[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$. Riemann-Lebesgue Theorem gives that the integral converges. For $a<0$, the problem are the points $x=\pm\pi/2$. Near those points $\cos(x)$ is the same as $\sin(x)$ is near $x=0$. The Taylor series (the first non-zero term) gives you how fast this function tends to 0. You can write $\sin(x)=x\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$. Here $\sin(x)/x$ can be defined as $1$ to be continuous at $x=0$. So, the convergence will have the same character as that of $x$.

Comment: @IrbidMath something can go wrong if $a<0$

Comment: @user Same as whay NBD said until $a<0$

Comment: @NDB Sorry, I don't understand. Can you post it as an answer maybe? (I tried to do simillar things)

Comment: @Ercanayan Yes, a is real (I edited the post)

Comment: @Lior, Atleast for $a≥0$, It gives a nice closed form $\beta \left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1+a}{2}\right)$

Comment: @Lior And for $\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} (\cos{x})^a \ dx$, when we take $0≥a$, for a trivial case of $a=-1$, we have$\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} (\sec{x}) \ dx$, it  is divergent. I think we can conclude for any a less than 0, it diverges

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your first consideration is fine, we need to consider the case $a<0$, then since we have

- at $x=\frac \pi 2$

$$\cos x = \left(\frac \pi 2 - x\right)+O(x^3)$$

- at $x=-\frac \pi 2$

$$\cos x = \left(\frac \pi 2 + x\right)+O(x^3)$$

the naure of the given integral at these points can be compared with $\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \left(\frac \pi 2 - x\right)^a \ dx$ and $\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{0} \left(\frac \pi 2 + x\right)^a \ dx$, therefore also your guess looks fine and you can use this observation to formalize your conclusion.

Comment: Actually, I tried to using Taylor series as NBD suggested. So, I did exactly what you mentioned above. I'm having trouble going on from here.

Comment: @Lior By $\pi/2-x=y$ integral $\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \left(\frac \pi 2 - x\right)^a \ dx=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} y^a \ dy$ which indeed converge for $-1<a<0$. To conclude we can refer to [limit comparison test](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1906781/limit-comparison-test-for-improper-integrals#:~:text=The%20proof%20goes%20by%20using%20the%20definition%20of,upper%20boundedness%20by%20a%20function%20whose%20integral%20converges.).

Comment: Sorry, I need to see a detailed answer. It's obvious to use the limit comparison test (the $O(x^3)$ implies that).  I think the limit itself isn't clear to me and also that you meet the conditions of limit comparison test (for example, both functions need to have the same "problematic point"). Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Lior You don't need more than that to conclude. At the problematic ponts the behaviour is "equivalent" to that given integrals. This reasoning is formalized referring to limit comparison test.

Comment: Cool. Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome! I don’t understand why answer has been downvoted!